# AI model loses accuracy after loading from save

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have attached my code here:

```
import easylog
import os

easylog.info("Begin importing necessary libraries")
try:
    import pandas as pd
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'pandas' [1 of 13]")
    import re
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 're' [2 of 13]")

    from sklearn import preprocessing
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'sklearn.preprocessing' [3 of 13]")
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split' [4 of 13]")

    import tensorflow as tf
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow' [5 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam' [6 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer' [7 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences' [8 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.models.Sequential' [9 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.layers.LSTM' [10 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense' [11 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout' [12 of 13]")
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
    easylog.pos("Successfully loaded 'tensorflow.keras.layers.Embedding' [13 of 13]")
except Exception as e:
    easylog.crit("Error while loading critical libraries!")
    easylog.crit(str(e))
    exit()

print(tf.__version__)

while True:
    inp = input("Load existing emotion model? y/n >")
    if inp == "n":
        existing = False
        break
    elif inp == "y":
        existing = True
        break
    else:
        print("Please type only 'y' or 'n'")



TEST_SIZE = 0.2

LEARNING_RATE = 0.00146

REQUIRED_TRAIN_ACCURACY = 0.9
REQUIRED_VAL_ACCURACY = REQUIRED_TRAIN_ACCURACY

NUM_EPOCHS = 5

DROPOUT = 0.2


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data/emotions/train.txt",sep=";",names=["Text","Emotion"])
category = pd.get_dummies(data.Emotion)
new_data = pd.concat([data, category], axis=1)
new_data = new_data.drop(columns="Emotion")
text = new_data["Text"].values
label = new_data[["anger", "fear", "joy", "love", "sadness", "surprise"]].values

text_train, text_val, label_train, label_val = train_test_split(text, label, test_size=TEST_SIZE)
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000, oov_token='x')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text_train)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text_val)

seq_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text_train)
seq_val = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text_val)

padded_train = pad_sequences(seq_train)
padded_val = pad_sequences(seq_val)


if existing == False:
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
        
    ])

    Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='Adam')
    model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics='categorical_accuracy')
    model.summary()
    

    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
            if(logs.get('categorical_accuracy') > REQUIRED_TRAIN_ACCURACY and logs.get('val_categorical_accuracy') > REQUIRED_VAL_ACCURACY):
                easylog.pos("Training complete!")
                self.model.stop_training = True
    callbacks = myCallback()

    easylog.info("Training model...")
    

    history = model.fit(padded_train, label_train, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_data=(padded_val, label_val), verbose=1, callbacks=[callbacks])
    easylog.pos("Training complete!")
    model.save('models/emotions/net', overwrite=True)
    model.save_weights("models/emotions/weights", overwrite=True)
    easylog.info("Model saved. Verifying...")
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_val, label_val)
    easylog.pos("Model verified!")
    print(f"accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
    plt.plot(history.history['categorical_accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_categorical_accuracy'])
    plt.title('Accuracy Model')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

    # Plot Loss
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('Loss Model')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
    plt.show()
else:
    easylog.info("Loading model...")
    try:
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model("models/emotions/net", compile=False)
        model.summary()
        model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics='categorical_accuracy')
        model.load_weights("models/emotions/weights")
        easylog.pos("Model loaded.")
        loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_val, label_val)
        easylog.pos("Model verified.")
        print(f"accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
    except Exception as e:
        easylog.err("Error while loading model!")
        easylog.err(str(e))
```

For some reason, my model isn't properly reloading after a save. Before saving, it has an accuracy of high 80s. After reloading, it is down in the low 30s.

I trained a model. At the end, the console said this:

```
[ SUCCESS ] - Training complete!
[ INFO ] - Model saved. Verifying...
100/100 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 0.3948 - categorical_accuracy: 0.8819
[ SUCCESS ] - Model verified!
accuracy: 88.19%
```

When I reran the code and selected for it to use the existing model, I was expecting to get something like this:

```
[ SUCCESS ] - Model loaded.
100/100 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: low number - categorical_accuracy: 0.88ish
[ SUCCESS ] - Model verified.
accuracy: 88ish%
```

Instead, I get this:

```
[ SUCCESS ] - Model loaded.
100/100 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 5.3685 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3125
[ SUCCESS ] - Model verified.
accuracy: 31.25%
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem setting the weights. I would not set explicitly the weights and load the model with the keras API as follows:

```
...
else:
    easylog.info("Loading model...")
    try:
        model = tf.keras.saving.load_model("models/emotions/net.keras") # Save the model with extension .keras
        model.summary()
        easylog.pos("Model loaded.")
        loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_val, label_val)
        easylog.pos("Model verified.")
        print(f"accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
    except Exception as e:
        easylog.err("Error while loading model!")
        easylog.err(str(e))
```

Notice that the module is different, tk.keras.models.load_model is substituted by [tf.keras.saving.load_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/saving/load_model). According to the doc, it is the recommended way to load model saved with the model.save() method as you did.

Additionally, it compiles the model by default in the same way you saved it. Not sure if it is the safest mode for production, but should solve the your issue.

You should save the model with a proper name in a .keras extension (or any other legacy format).